Too many zeroes in tick labels
I am often having this problem when plotting in version 14.0.0.0  for MacOSX x86 (64bit). Is there a solution? Ideally not having to define explicitly all tick labels for all plots?
Plot[{1, 1 + (0.5 - 1)*Exp[-t]}, {t, 0, 3}, Frame -> True]


EDIT:
It seems that the issue affects more than plotting
In[3]:= Round[0.7, 0.1]

Out[3]= 0.7000000000000001


in V 14.1 on windows, I do not get what you show. Screen shot. https://i.sstatic.net/6GJL3wBM.png

In 14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024) everything is fine.

In principle, it should not happen with your code. Maybe it is a simplified code, and this thing happens in a real one?  Anyway, there is a workaround: just include the option: Ticks -> {Automatic, Round[#, 0.01] & /@ Range[{0.7, 1.0, 0.1}]}.

I cannot reproduce your problem with "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" (macOS  Sequoia  15.1 on MBP M2 Pro)

Have you possibly been playing with the display settings for numbers? You find this under menu Edit ▶ Preferences ▶ Appearance ▶ Numbers ▶ Formatting.

Looks like you set SetOptions[$FrontEnd, PrintPrecision -> 16] or higher, or set the options for $FrontEndSession. This option may be set in the preferences dialog as Domen pointed out. PrintPrecision controls how many digits of machine floats are printed. The default is 6; trailing zeros are normally not printed.

Yes, that was it. I set back to default and the problem is solved. thanks!
